# Difference between amd64 and i386 version of Ubuntu

Tags: 64-bit, 32-bit, c

Can anyone explain the difference between these versions of Ubuntu?

I installed 11.10 i386 and wrote some C code that worked fine in that platform but failed to work in 11.10 amd64 on the same machine.

After debugging with `valgrind` and `gdb` I got that I was getting `segmentation fault` in a call to `realloc()` with an argument `mem_ptr` and size `0` passed to it.

I learned here that i386 is also referred to as 32-bit and amd64 as 64-bit, but what does this mean?

CPU: Intel i7 2nd generation

Comment: VTR as although this is clearly related to the called duplicate, the comments indicate a more in depth question here that doesn't appear to be a candidate for merging.